# In Android How to Use Tab Layout in Alert Dialog Box?

Tags: android

[image]
In Android Application I want to **Customize Alert Dialog Box** shown below.Alert Dialog contain a Tab Layout With 3 Tabs.

Comment: ok ,so show up what you have performed till now

Answer (score 0):

Create a `XML` with the desired views (including the table) and call

```
View view = // instantiate it. Maybe with LayoutInflater(?)

new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext)
     .setView(view);
     .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent Activity with Tab Layout..
Check this link for creating tab layout [clickhere](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Check this out for transparent activity [clickhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)